# Some users see different number of list items on page layout

Tags: page-layout, list, related-list, configuration

Some users only see the first 5 items in a related list where as other users see the full list on the page layout.

Is there a way of controlling this so that all users only see the first 5 items for each related list on the page layout?

Comment: If they click "Show more" SF remembers that for some period of time (not sure on the criteria). And I do not believe you can customize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic Related List mode, the user can choose to view more or fewer records at once by clicking on the "more / fewer" options at the bottom of the related list. The administrator cannot override this. If you enable "separate loading of related lists" in Setup > Customize > User Interface, then the default value will be 5, and users can load more records by using the "More" option.